# Laravel split() returns a mix of arrays and objects

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to [split](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-split) an array into two parts.

```
$collection = collect( [1, 2, 15, 16] );

$groups = $collection->split( 2 );
```

The results are... mixed:

```
(2) [Array(2), {…}]
    0: Array(2)
        0: 1
        1: 2
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array(0)
    1: 
        2: 15
        3: 16
        __proto__: Object
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

I am not sure if it is a bug or I am missing something. If I split into more groups, the first one is always an array and others are objects. Why does it do that and how can I make the output type consistent?

---

P.S. A quick solution is to use `array_chunk( $collection, 2 )` if the collections happens to be an array with numeric indexes as in the case of this example. According to the answer below, if the indexes are not numeric, then this problem should not occur.

Comment: What does `__proto__` property do there? I think this result is from the javascript console

Comment: @YouneL Hmm good point. It is from console. I guess perhaps by the time it arrives to the front end something happens to it. I need to look into that

Comment: Nothing happens to anything. `json_encoding` array with numeric keys starting not from `0` gives you an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an obvious example:

```
$a = [[1,2], [2 => 2, 3 => 3]];
echo json_encode($a);
```

Output is:

```
[[1,2],{"2":2,"3":3}]
```

First element will be **array** because keys in it **are** zero-indexed, second will be **object**, because keys in it are **not** zero-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you probably missing something.
if you split a collection, the result will be collection of collections:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1178
#items: array:2 [
    0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1177
      #items: array:2 [
        0 => 1
        1 => 2
      ]
    }
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1156
      #items: array:2 [
        2 => 15
        3 => 16
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You also need to call `$groups->toArray()` method as well.